# The type initilizer for "j8" threw exception Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

When i am selecting PreEmptive Dotfuscator and Analytics in Tools with that running in VS 2012 I am facing  the issue below, it is an exception that pops up.

How can i resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From: http://www.preemptive.com/forum/topic?f=18&t=23523

> If you are running into this error message can you please try adding the “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\KitsRoot” registry key and give it the same value as "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\KitsRoot"

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Steve http://exe-steve.blogspot.in/2013/06/visual-studion-dotfuscator-community.html

If you are running into this error message can you please try adding the

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\KitsRoot`

registry key and give it the same value as

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\KitsRoot`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was keys were `missing in both registry location` ..

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots
```

I found those keys in another machine.. and created two `.reg` file to `import` these values in my computer `registry`

> first.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots]
"KitsRoot"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\"
"WindowsDebuggersRoot"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\Debuggers\\"
"AppVerifier64BitAutomationRoot"="C:\\Program Files\\Application Verifier\\"
"AppVerifier32BitAutomationRoot"="C:\\Program Files\\Application Verifier\\"
```

> second.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots]
"KitsRoot"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\"
"WindowsDebuggersRoot"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\Debuggers\\"
"AppVerifier64BitAutomationRoot"="C:\\Program Files\\Application Verifier\\"
"AppVerifier32BitAutomationRoot"="C:\\Program Files\\Application Verifier\\"
```

Once both file created just `double click on those .reg` files to add keys on these locations .. `Great!!` now it's working for me!!