# PreEmptive Dotfuscator

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, dotfuscator

I already saw a brief answer on the following post:

[The type initilizer for "j8" threw exception Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890137/the-type-initilizer-for-j8-threw-exception-visual-studio-2012)

I don't have much experience with the registry, so can someone guide me a little more, or if there is a different solution out there please explain.

Thanks very much!!

Comment: You probably want to ask this question on http://superuser.com instead of here. This tutorial-ish thing about the registry might help some: http://www.akadia.com/services/windows_registry_tutorial.html